# Configuration property not recognized

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to define two data sources for my spring app because I want to alternate between them.
Firstly I am defining the datasources in application.properties like so

```
# First DataSource
spring.datasource.datasource1.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.3.89:3306
spring.datasource.datasource1.username=sendnotification1
spring.datasource.datasource1.password=a1s2d3f4
spring.datasource.datasource1.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
# Second DataSource
spring.datasource.datasource2.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.3.22:3306
spring.datasource.datasource2.username=mysqluser
spring.datasource.datasource2.password=x=47rFG_
spring.datasource.datasource2.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

then I am making a config class for the datasource

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource1")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.datasource1")
    public DataSource dataSource1() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    @Bean(name = "dataSource2")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.datasource2")
    public DataSource dataSource2() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

and then a config class for JdbcTemplate

```
@Configuration
public class JdbcTemplateConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate1")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate1(@Qualifier("dataSource1") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate2")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2(@Qualifier("dataSource2") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

and each time I am autowiring a new instance of Jdbctemplate I am specifying the bean like so

```
@Autowired
    public ActualizareDataAccessService(@Qualifier("jdbcTemplate1")JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
```

the problem is that somehow Spring doesn't recognize the datasources from application.properties because it does not find the prefix so i am getting warnings like these

**Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.datasource.datasource1.url'**

and when I run it, it throws this exception

**Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.**

application.properties is located at `src/main/resources/application.properties`

Comment: Please post where your application.properties is stored.

Comment: @Grim I have updated it

Comment: What to do is explained in detail in the documentation -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources. The key is to define the `DataSourceProperties` as well and bind the properties to that, then use that to create a datasource. Currently you are creating a datasource asnd binding to the resulting datasource instead of the datasource properties.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you. don't know how I missed this